# How to exclude column from create, but validate in edit in flask-admin?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

To remove fields from the create and edit forms:

```
form_excluded_columns = ['last_name', 'email']
```

I want to label edited rows with comments. For example we create row with columns:
name, count, payment. After we edit payment column, we MUST append comment about why we change this.

How to apply such behavior in flask-admin?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
form_create_rules = [rules.FieldSet('name', 'count', 'payment')]
form_edit_rules = [rules.FieldSet('comment')]
form_args = dict(comment=dict(validators=[required()]))
```

Solve my problem, but I can't reject the feeling, I'm doing something wrong.